# custom grafana connection to Prometheus returns forbidden

Tags: openshift, prometheus, grafana

I am trying to set up grafana in openshift talking to Prometheus and I am following this

https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/custom-grafana-dashboards-red-hat-openshift-container-platform-4

this has been working till today and now I get

[image]

I am really confused as I am outting the right token and not sure what goes wrong that I cannot connect it any more
anyone else experiencing the same issue?

Comment: please share your CRs for the grafana instance